# Generating gameboard fillword game

Tags: javascript, html, random

there's a problem . I'm make fillword game . And I need to implement a random level generation . Levels now seem static. How can I implement this ? Help me please...
Now levels look like this -

```
var rooms = {
  board: [
  [ 'U', 'C', 'W', 'G', 'U', 'B', 'T', 'Z', 'Y', 'K', 'C', 'T' ],
  [ 'K', 'B', 'N', 'A', 'Z', 'B', 'U', 'J', 'L', 'I', 'D', 'J' ],
  [ 'I', 'J', 'S', 'R', 'I', 'A', 'A', 'H', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'D' ],
  [ 'T', 'L', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'P', 'V', 'U', 'H', 'T', 'R' ],
  [ 'C', 'O', 'L', 'G', 'O', 'H', 'A', 'W', 'N', 'O', 'V', 'C' ],
  [ 'H', 'U', 'A', 'E', 'U', 'R', 'R', 'V', 'D', 'U', 'I', 'N' ],
  [ 'E', 'V', 'T', 'T', 'V', 'O', 'T', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'N', 'U' ],
  [ 'N', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'W', 'O', 'M', 'F', 'Y', 'E', 'H', 'R' ],
  [ 'A', 'B', 'A', 'S', 'E', 'M', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'U', 'U', 'S' ],
  [ 'A', 'T', 'T', 'I', 'C', 'Y', 'N', 'Q', 'A', 'U', 'J', 'E' ],
  [ 'O', 'C', 'U', 'Y', 'Y', 'E', 'T', 'X', 'C', 'Z', 'O', 'R' ],
  [ 'B', 'E', 'D', 'R', 'O', 'O', 'M', 'X', 'M', 'Q', 'X', 'Y' ]   
  ],
words: [
"HOUSE",
"BATHROOM",
"BEDROOM",
"KITCHEN",
"ATTIC",
"BASEMENT",
"APARTMENT",
"GARAGE",
"HALL",
"NURSERY",
"LAUNDRY",
]
};
```

Can help somebody?
There is build of the game - http://rakapudl.github.io/fillword/

Comment: It's not that simple. You can't just generate a random array. You need to check that the game is valid (all the word are available to mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great javascript library https://github.com/bunkat/wordfind with many functions that you may need in the future. To solve your problem you need only 2 functions from that library:

1) Generate a valid table from given words

2) Get a solution so that people can find out words they didn't find.

In order to generate a table you will need to change print function so that it looks like this:

```
populate: function (puzzle) {
    let table = [];
    for (var i = 0, height = puzzle.length; i < height; i++) {
      var row = puzzle[i];
      let rowUpperCase = row.map((letter) => {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
      });
      table.push(rowUpperCase);      
    }

    return table;
  }
```

We need to upper case each letter, because they are lowercase by default.

To get a solution we also need to adopt solve method for your case.

```
solve: function (puzzle, words) {
    var options = {
                    height:       puzzle.length,
                    width:        puzzle[0].length,
                    orientations: allOrientations,
                    preferOverlap: true
                  },
        found = [];

    for(var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
      var word = words[i],
          locations = findBestLocations(puzzle, options, word);

      if (locations.length > 0 && locations[0].overlap ===     word.length) {
        locations[0].word = word;

        if (locations[0].orientation == 'vertical') {
          found.push(
            locations[0].x,
            locations[0].y,
            locations[0].x,
            locations[0].y+locations[0].word.length -1
          );
        }

        if (locations[0].orientation == 'horizontal') {
          found.push(
            locations[0].x,
            locations[0].y,
            locations[0].x +locations[0].word.length -1 ,
            locations[0].y
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return found;
  }
```

So now you can have you table generated like this

```
table = populate(words);
```

And solution will be

```
solve = solve(puzzle, words);
```

That's it!